# Superclass/subclass constructor usage

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I am trying to construct multiple objects from an object stored in a Map (the GameObject is what I am copying). But the types I want to be copied are sub-types of GameObject like Wall and Turret. If I have a public GameObject(GameObject go){ } method declared in my superclass and public Turret(Turret t){ } defined in my subclass, will the object in the Map use the subclasses constructor? I know this is true for methods, just not sure about objects. I have tried searching, this seems to me like a very fundamental question of oop, but it's a hard thing to search for and any input would be really appreciated! :D

Just for a short example of what I want.

```
Map<String, GameObject> equipment = new HashMap<String, GameObject>();
equipment.put("turret", new Turret(x, y));//turret extends PlaceableGameObject which       extends GameObject
if(user clicks){
    GameObect tempObject = new Turret(equipment.get("turret"));
    tempObject.setX(click.getX());
    tempObject.setY(click.getY());
    board.put(tempObject);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking: if `Turret` extends `GameObject`, and you make a `Turret`, is the code in `GameObject`'s constructor called?

Comment: Yes, also if the constructors are defined in both cases which will be called?

Comment: Not clear what you asking. Might `Factory` be useful in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I ended up doing which worked for me was to write a getNew(int x, int y) method in my superclass and all my subclasses. This returned the correct object.

Comment: because good sir, your solution gives me a GameObject, and not a Turret as you said. Please kindly remove your downvote for this error1

Comment: The object is Turret, but you create reference as GameObject. And remember there is no my solution. There is answer to your question "will the object in the Map use the subclasses constructor?"

Comment: I don't want points man! I want a solution that works. Using a superclass consntructor creates an instance of the superclass. My question was, as stated above, is there any way to call a superclass constructor that will call the proper subclasses constructor. Thanks for your answer, but it just plain doesn't work. Downvoting my question and answer doesn't change that.

Comment: You didn't ask about any solution, you ask the question which my answer completely answers. See the quoted part of the answer.

Comment: You downvoted every single question I've ever asked. That's not cool man. I would appreciate it if you upvoted that which you downvoted. I reported you. That is unacceptable, and you should be banned.

Comment: I have also reported you about silent and mean unaccept of correct answer.

Comment: You have first accepted answer, which has no sense and which is accepted by you. Congratulations!

Answer (score 2):

> Are you asking: if Turret extends GameObject, and you make a Turret, is the code in GameObject's constructor called?
>
> Yes, also if the constructors are defined in both cases which will be called?

`Turret` constructor would call `GameObject` constructor implicitly.

From [Inheritance Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html):

"You can write a subclass constructor that invokes the constructor of the superclass, either implicitly or by using the keyword super."

Comment: Would the resulting object that is added to the board be a Turret or a GameObject in the case I provided?

Comment: The object itself would be Turret, since you call Turrent constructor expliocitly, but GameObject - base class would be also initialized.